# How to use keyboard to drop-down a menu in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, cell

I have a drop-down menu created in an excel cell. Everytime I want to enter a value in that cell, after I navigate the focus to that cell using keyboard, I am not able to drop the drop-down menu using keyboard. I have to click the downward pointing arrow using mouse and then make a choice from the menu.

[image]

I want to know is there a keyboard short-cut to achieve the same? (I am quite sure there would be some short-cut that is there...)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Then left arrow to select the top, and up/down again to select from within. Enter to choose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jüri Ruut. I have been wasting a lot of time moving mouse around.

Comment: this is buggy on Mac... some cells will show the data validation list, for some cells it will show values from other cells on the same column...

Comment: On my Mac, this worked for me: tab into the cell, then hit a space, then hit backspace/delete. The list pops up!